# Thymeleaf pagination work not as described

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, pagination, thymeleaf

I have **Thymeleaf** pagination at **departments** page, which work good, but i have one problem.

When i try to update department **name**, this renamed department gone from page and shown at last page as last row.

How can i fix this? I want to update departments name and have it on the same place, not at the end.

This is my code.

**Service:**

```
public Page<Department> findPaginatedDepartments(final Pageable pageable) {
        List<Department> departments = departmentRepository.findAll();
        int pageSize = pageable.getPageSize();
        int currentPage = pageable.getPageNumber();
        int startItem = currentPage * pageSize;
        final List<Department> list;

        if (departments.size() < startItem) {
            list = Collections.emptyList();
        } else {
            int toIndex = Math.min(startItem + pageSize, departments.size());
            list = departments.subList(startItem, toIndex);
        }
        return new PageImpl<>(list, PageRequest.of(currentPage, pageSize), departments.size());
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
 @GetMapping()
    public String getAllDepartments(
            Model model,
            @RequestParam("page") Optional<Integer> page,
            @RequestParam("size") Optional<Integer> size) {
        int currentPage = page.orElse(1);
        int pageSize = size.orElse(10);

        Page<Department> departmentPage = departmentService.findPaginatedDepartments(PageRequest.of(currentPage - 1, pageSize));
        model.addAttribute("departmentPage", departmentPage);
        int totalPages = departmentPage.getTotalPages();
        if (totalPages > 0) {
            List<Integer> pageNumbers = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, totalPages)
                    .boxed()
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            model.addAttribute("pageNumbers", pageNumbers);
        }
        return "/department/departments";
    }
```

**View:**

```
<div class="departments_wrapper main_menu_wrapper">
    <div id="dep-grid" class="departments_table highlight">
        <div class="head_departments">
            <span class="head-left-grid" th:onclick="'javascript:sortDepartments()'">Name<i id="arrow-sort" class="tiny material-icons arrow-sort-button">expand_more</i></span>
            <span class="head-right-grid">Edit</span>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <div class="dep-body" th:each="department : ${departmentPage.content}">
                <li id="dep-li" class="left-column" th:text="${department.name}"></li>
                <li class="right-column">
                    <div class="dep_edit">
                        <a id="dep-modal-pic" class="edit_dep modal-trigger" href="#modal3"
                           th:onclick="'javascript:showFunctionModal(\'' + ${department.id} +'\' , \'' + ${department.name} +'\');'"><i
                                class="material-icons">more_horiz</i></a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="pagination pagination-dep">
        <ul>
            <li class="disabled"><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i></a></li>
            <li><a th:if="${departmentPage.totalPages > 0}" th:each="pageNumber : ${pageNumbers}"
                   th:href="@{/departments(size=${departmentPage.size}, page=${pageNumber})}" th:text="${pageNumber}"
                   th:class="${pageNumber==departmentPage.number + 1} ? active"></a></li>
            <li class="disabled"><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Update Department name

```
@Transactional
public void updateDepartment(final Long id, final Department department) {
    final Department departmentFound = departmentRepository.getOne(id);
    departmentFound.setName(department.getName());
    departmentRepository.saveAndFlush(departmentFound);
}
```

Comment: Can you also show the service which you update the department name as well as your Department class?

Comment: Added code. but i think the problem is on the pagination.

Comment: I did a testing with exact same code except with my own entity. I couldn't reproduce the same issue you are saying and I check the underlying implementation of the pagination is using ArrayList all the time which preserve the ordering. I suggest you to run on debugging mode and put a breakpoint after returning result from the findPaginatedDepartments method in your service and check if the result is following the correct order like when you manually query the db with "select * from department"

Comment: I found some things.
In my table all looks lie this
`8 dep8
9 dep9
10 dep10
15 dep15
16 dep16
17 deptest`
And when i edit any of them, it will become last in db

Comment: Found very interesting thing. When i update field in pgAdmin it is also work not correctly. Updated field go down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
After many time of search i find, that it is the postgres `"feature"`.
So, in my **DepartmentService** i just wrote comparator, which will sort **Departments** by id.
And this solved my problem.

```
 final Comparator<Department> cmp = Comparator.comparing(Department::getId);
```

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the available crud methods in the repository. Some offer pagination feature and sorting as well.
This is because by using repository.findAll() retrieve all results and then filter & sort by using code which tends to be inefficient when the resultset become huge.

Comment: I am already using pagination, but if will be something more interesting i will use it.